# Print a string in JSON format in bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, fastcgi, jq

I am using below statement in my CGI bash scrip, which is returning me error `[error] 1705#0: *105 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream [...]`. Is this a correct way to use it?

```
echo "{\"meta\": {\"link\": {\"upload\": { \"href\": \"http://${ip}${target}\"}}}, \"status\": \"empty\"}" | jq .
```

My expected output is as below.

```
{
  "meta": {
  "link": {
  "upload": { "href": "http://fileserver.example.com/upload/content/{id}" }
  }
},"status": "empty"
}
```

Comment: `echo` should work fine. And you should get the expected result. Seems issue with `FastCGI` for that see this - http://serverfault.com/questions/474215/serve-a-fastcgi-through-nginx

Comment: There is **no issue** with `FastCGI` as other scripts are running fine on the same setup. Only this one is causing some problem.

Comment: @Shashank, how about a simple test like `jq <<< '{"a":10}'`? Also use `printf` instead of `echo`: `printf "%s" '{"meta": ...}'`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Tried that too, doesn't help. Still getting same error.

Comment: @Shashank, then you have server configuration issues (if the test file is really as simple as that line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no configuration issue. The problem was caused because there was no response from the script for the POST request.